# Temporarily prevent SMB file from being locked in-use - Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, server-message-block

I have a file `\\server\share\myApp\app.exe` that a handful of people run directly from the share. I need to update that file occasionally, but it is usually locked due to the open SMB sessions.

My normal procedure for similar SMB locked files is to close the files and sessions locking them like:

```
$openAppFiles = Get-SmbOpenFile | Where Path -like 'D:\Shares\myApp\*' 
$appSessions  = $openAppFiles | Select SessionID -Unique

Close-SmbOpenFile -FileID $openAppFiles.FileID -Force
Close-SmbSession -SessionID $appSessions.SessionID -Force

Extract-Archive $newZip -Destination 'D:\Shares\myApp\' -Force
```

But lately, I have run into issues where a client is able to reconnect and lock one or more of the files I'm updating within that tiny window. I can test trying to just rename a file for example:

```
Rename-Item .\app.exe .\app.exe.bak

[Error] Rename-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Is there a way for me to temporarily block clients from accessing these files?

I've considered turning off the share temporarily, but I would have to do it after-hours. I can also just keep re-running it until it works, but that doesn't necessarily solve the issue either. What other options can I try?

Comment: Is t!he executable something you can change e.g. by let the developer change it in a certain way? If yes change it in a way that it is started from SMB first copies itself to the local temp path and then starts the copied version. The first process can then end and leave the executable unlocked.

Comment: @Robert unfortunately not from either end. I can't change `app` itself, and there's another piece of software involved that executes `app` which I can't modify either. The smb sessions aren't even needed after the app is launched, but it seems like windows clients will re-establish them anyways as long as the process is running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding **Deny Everyone** entry to share's ACL:

`Block-SmbShareAccess -Name AppShare -AccountName Everyone -Force`

Next, proceed with disconnecting connected users like you do in your script.

After the app is updated, remove **Deny Everyone** entry from ACL:

`Unblock-SmbShareAccess -Name AppShare -AccountName Everyone -Force`